# KNN does not take into account the actual magnitude of the distance

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

Suppose I have 3 two dimensional points $(0, 0), (10000000, 0), (-1, 0)$ and $(0, 0)$ has label 1.0. If we were to use 1-NN to predict the label for $(10000000, 0), (-1, 0)$, then the answer for both are $1.0$. This does not make sense since the actual distance (Euclidean distance) from $(10000000, 0)$ to $(0,0)$ is way larger than the distance from $(-1,0)$ to $(0,0)$. How could their prediction result be the same? Intuitively, we should be more confident predicting the label of $(-1, 0)$ to be 1.0. Is there a way to reflect this confidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We actually *should not* be more confident in one of the label assignments because according to the assumption made by our learner, both label assignments are equally valid; for a $k$-NN classifier we $k=1$ we assign each unlabelled item to the class of its closest neighbour. That is because we rely strongly on the [*contiguity hypothesis*](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/vector-space-classification-1.html): "*items of the same class form a contiguous region and regions of different classes do not overlap.*"

For $k>1$, we assign each new item to the majority class of its $k$ closest neighbours with the rationale being that based on the contiguity hypothesis, an item will have the same label as the majority of other known items located in its neighbourhood. We can have a probabilistic output (i.e. quantification of confidence) based on the fraction each class. This brings back to the original example for $k=1$ presented by the OP. The prediction for both unlabelled points *has to* be the same because there is no other alternative.

As an immediate work-around, we could define some radius $d$ outside which there is no concept of neighbourhood. This would be akin to find use [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) to label points as inliers or outliers and then use 1NN to classify inlier points only. More formally, there are methodologies like Hubness Information k-Nearest Neighbor ([HIKNN](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1553374.1553485) (2009)) where all neighbours are not "treated equally" extending standard $k$-NN assumptions (and have subsequent impact to our outputs). There is also a reasonable literature on [proximity graph methods for nearest neighbours](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.5555/3524938.3525661) (2020) if one wants to dig this deeper.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Even though I do have the hubness problem. However I cannot try to 'reduce' them because most of the points only have one same neighbor in the problem I faced. I want a method to penalize the estimate based on the distance. One quick thought would be cosine distance * estimate. However that only calculated $P(A = B) * \text{Prediction of B}$, which does not feel correct.

Comment: Happy to help. I think in this case one should move away from 1NN. It is a noisy method after all. And if as you say "*most of the points only have one same neighbour*" then it makes sense to question whether using a neighbour-based classifier even makes sense. Being informal: $k$NN are relevant in "smallish" ($<10$) dimensions that can be reasonably normalised.